# Elasticsearch "query_string" query error displays as "Lexical error"

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

**App version** 
Elasticsearch: v.7.1 
Laravel: v5.8

**OS version**: Ubuntu 18 (server) / Windows 10 (dev PCs)

The "query_string" query of the Elasticsearch search API returns an error message of something like "Lexical error" -- telling there's something wrong in the query.

**Steps to reproduce**:

a. We're using the "query_string" query that contains **4629 characters** (including alphabet and symbols such as parentheses and double quotes) 
b. When we're querying using our PHP and Python applications, the error mentioned in the title pops up

[image: error]
[image: error2]

**Main question**

Am I doing something wrong here or is it an application-level error/bug? Been trying alternatives like using "simple_query_string" but it has a different behavior, so we're really keen on using the **query_string** query of Elasticsearch

**Here's the query**

```
"query_string" => [
    "fields" => ['title', 'content'],
    "query" => """
        (("Salvador "Sal" San Buenaventura Panelo")) OR ("Christopher Lawrence Go") OR ("DILG Undersecretary Epimaco Densing") OR ("Rodolfo Fariñas") OR ("Francis Tolentino" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Reynaldo V. Umali" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Bong Revilla") OR (("Jose "Joe" Callangan Calida")) OR ("Gus S. Tambunting" OR "GusTambunting" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Ramon Bong Revilla" OR "Bong Revilla" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR (Lacson) OR ("Francis Ng Tolentino") OR ("Jose Calida") OR ("José Ruperto Martín Marfori Andanar") OR ("Prospero Pichay Jr.") OR ("Pantaleon Alvarez" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Prospero Pichay" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Senator Vicente Sotto") OR ("Paolo "Pulong" Zimmerman Duterte") OR ("Prospero Arreza Pichay Jr.") OR ("Rudy Fariñas" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Paolo Duterte") OR ("Rudy Fariñas") OR ("Fredenil Castro") OR ("Salvador B. Belaro Jr.") OR ("Sen. Imee Marcos") OR ("Manny Pacquiao") OR ("Senator Aquilino "Koko" Pimentel III" OR "Sen. Aquilino "Koko" Pimentel III") OR ("Senator Aquilino Pimentel III" OR "Sen. Aquilino Pimentel III" OR "Senator Aquilino Pimentel") OR ("Senator Vicente C. Sotto III") OR ("Tito Sotto") OR ("Bato dela Rosa") OR ("Sen. Bato") OR ("Hon. Reynaldo V. Umali") OR ("Gus S. Tambunting") OR ("Tito Sotto" OR "Senator Vicente Sotto" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Bato dela Rosa" OR "Senator Ronald "Bato" dela Rosa"("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Bong Go" OR "Christopher Lawrence Go" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Paolo Duterte" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Fredenil H. Castro" OR "Fredenil Castro" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Koko Pimentel") OR ("Paolo Zimmerman Duterte") OR ("Pantaleon Diaz Alvarez") OR ("Salvador Belaro" AND ("De Lima" OR "Leila De Lima")) OR ("Ramon Revilla") OR ("Senator Bong Go") OR (Panfilo) OR ("Jose Callangan Calida") OR ("Salvador San Buenaventura Panelo") OR ("Pantaleon "Bebot" Diaz Alvarez") OR ("Fredenil H. Castro" OR "Fredenil Castro") OR ("Salvador Belaro Jr.") OR ("Salvador Belaro") OR ("Reynaldo V. Umali") OR ("Senator Koko Pimentel III) OR ("Sen. AND Koko AND Pimentel AND III" OR "Sen. AND Koko AND Pimentel") OR ("Bong AND Go") OR ("Ramon AND Bong AND Revilla") OR ("Senator AND Panfilo AND Lacson" OR "Panfilo AND Lacson" OR "Ping AND Lacson" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Manny AND Pacquiao" OR "Senator AND Manny AND Pacquiao" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Salvador AND Panelo" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Epimaco AND Densing" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Senator AND Sotto") OR ("Vicente AND Sotto") OR ("Panfilo AND Lacson" OR "Ping AND Lacson") OR ("Ronald AND dela AND Rosa") OR ("Senator AND Revilla") OR ("Prospero AND Pichay") OR ("Jose AND Calida" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Senator AND Francis AND Tolentino") OR ("Senator AND Ronald AND dela AND Rosa") OR ("Menardo AND Guevarra" OR "Menardo AND I. AND Guevarra") OR ("Rodolfo AND "Rudy" AND Castro AND Fariñas") OR ("Senator AND Imee AND Marcos" OR "Imee AND Marcos" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Gus AND S. AND Tambunting" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Ronald AND “Bato” AND dela AND Rosa") OR ("Senator AND Bato AND dela AND Rosa") OR ("Senator AND Ramon AND Revilla AND Jr.") OR ("Sen. AND Francis AND Tolentino") OR ("Francis AND Tolentino") OR (("María AND Imelda AND Josefa AND "Imee" AND Romualdez AND Marcos")) OR ("Pulong AND Duterte") OR ("Rodolfo AND Castro AND Fariñas") OR ("Menardo AND Guevarra" OR "Menardo AND I. AND Guevarra"("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Christopher AND Lawrence AND “Bong” AND Go") OR ("Senator AND Imee AND Marcos") OR ("Justice AND Secretary AND Menardo AND Guevarra" OR "Justice AND Secretary AND Menardo AND I. AND Guevarra") OR ("Epimaco AND Densing") OR ("Fredenil AND "Fred" AND H. AND Castro") OR ("Koko AND Pimentel" OR "Senator AND Aquilino AND Pimentel AND III" OR "Sen. AND Aquilino AND Pimentel AND III" OR "Senator AND Aquilino AND Pimentel" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Martín AND Andanar" ("De AND Lima" OR "Leila AND De AND Lima")) OR ("Senator AND Ronald AND "Bato" AND dela AND Rosa") OR ("Christopher AND Lawrence AND "Bong" AND Tesoro AND Go") OR ("Senator AND Christopher AND Lawrence AND "Bong" AND Tesoro AND Go") OR ("Senator AND Panfilo AND Lacson") OR ("Senator AND Manny AND Pacquiao") OR ("Salvador AND Panelo") OR ("Martín AND Andanar") OR ("Pantaleon AND Alvarez")
        """
```

Comment: Hard to tell... That's quite a long query... try to start with a single constraint and then add more constraints until it starts breaking.

Comment: The error states "*Encountered <EOF> after ...*", so the query string might be truncated because too big (?). It may also be due to non-escaped reserved characters : `+ - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`

Comment: yes sir @EricLavault we'ree presuming that the query is too long, but is there a way for the "query_string" to accept such query? because that's the behavior of our old system with the Sphinx :(

Comment: hello sir @Val, we're presuming that the error prompts because the query is too long, but whenever we're using the **simple_query_string** the whole query works, but what's dangerous with the **simple_query_string** is because it's not strict with the required keywords of the user

Comment: edit your question and add the query in text formate instead of image, then we can help you easily

Comment: You might want to check elastic' settings `http.max_content_length`. also you can log the entire request on the web servers side to check if it's actually sent correctly to elastic, then you can json_decode() it manually to see if there is any encoding issue.

Comment: Did you check my answer @JueViole17 ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes(`""`) from the `query` and try like below, hope it'll work then.

**Working Example on my index:**

```
GET locations/_search
  {
    "size": 1,
    "sort": [
      {
        "_score": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      },
      {
        "property_count": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    ],
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "country_code.keyword": "IT"
            }
          },
          {
            "query_string": {
              "fields": ["display","content"],
              "query": "((Salvador Sal San Buenaventura Panelo)) OR (Christopher Lawrence Go) OR (DILG Undersecretary Epimaco Densing) OR (Rodolfo Fariñas) OR (Francis Tolentino AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Reynaldo V. Umali AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Bong Revilla) OR ((Jose Joe Callangan Calida)) OR (Gus S. Tambunting OR GusTambunting AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Ramon Bong Revilla OR Bong Revilla AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Lacson) OR (Francis Ng Tolentino) OR (Jose Calida) OR (José Ruperto Martín Marfori Andanar) OR (Prospero Pichay Jr.) OR (Pantaleon Alvarez AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Prospero Pichay AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Senator Vicente Sotto) OR (Paolo Pulong Zimmerman Duterte) OR (Prospero Arreza Pichay Jr.) OR (Rudy Fariñas AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Paolo Duterte) OR (Rudy Fariñas) OR (Fredenil Castro) OR (Salvador B. Belaro Jr.) OR (Sen. Imee Marcos) OR (Manny Pacquiao) OR (Senator Aquilino Koko Pimentel III OR Sen. Aquilino Koko Pimentel III) OR (Senator Aquilino Pimentel III OR Sen. Aquilino Pimentel III OR Senator Aquilino Pimentel) OR (Senator Vicente C. Sotto III) OR (Tito Sotto) OR (Bato dela Rosa) OR (Sen. Bato) OR (Hon. Reynaldo V. Umali) OR (Gus S. Tambunting) OR (Tito Sotto OR Senator Vicente Sotto AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Bato dela Rosa OR Senator Ronald Bato dela Rosa(De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Bong Go OR Christopher Lawrence Go AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Paolo Duterte AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Fredenil H. Castro OR Fredenil Castro AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Koko Pimentel) OR (Paolo Zimmerman Duterte) OR (Pantaleon Diaz Alvarez) OR (Salvador Belaro AND (De Lima OR Leila De Lima)) OR (Ramon Revilla) OR (Senator Bong Go) OR (Panfilo) OR (Jose Callangan Calida) OR (Salvador San Buenaventura Panelo) OR (Pantaleon Bebot Diaz Alvarez) OR (Fredenil H. Castro OR Fredenil Castro) OR (Salvador Belaro Jr.) OR (Salvador Belaro) OR (Reynaldo V. Umali) OR (Senator Koko Pimentel III) OR (Sen. AND Koko AND Pimentel AND III OR Sen. AND Koko AND Pimentel) OR (Bong AND Go) OR (Ramon AND Bong AND Revilla) OR (Senator AND Panfilo AND Lacson OR Panfilo AND Lacson OR Ping AND Lacson (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Manny AND Pacquiao OR Senator AND Manny AND Pacquiao (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Salvador AND Panelo (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Epimaco AND Densing (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Senator AND Sotto) OR (Vicente AND Sotto) OR (Panfilo AND Lacson OR Ping AND Lacson) OR (Ronald AND dela AND Rosa) OR (Senator AND Revilla) OR (Prospero AND Pichay) OR (Jose AND Calida (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Senator AND Francis AND Tolentino) OR (Senator AND Ronald AND dela AND Rosa) OR (Menardo AND Guevarra OR Menardo AND I. AND Guevarra) OR (Rodolfo AND Rudy AND Castro AND Fariñas) OR (Senator AND Imee AND Marcos OR Imee AND Marcos (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Gus AND S. AND Tambunting (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Ronald AND “Bato” AND dela AND Rosa) OR (Senator AND Bato AND dela AND Rosa) OR (Senator AND Ramon AND Revilla AND Jr.) OR (Sen. AND Francis AND Tolentino) OR (Francis AND Tolentino) OR ((María AND Imelda AND Josefa AND Imee AND Romualdez AND Marcos)) OR (Pulong AND Duterte) OR (Rodolfo AND Castro AND Fariñas) OR (Menardo AND Guevarra OR Menardo AND I. AND Guevarra(De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Christopher AND Lawrence AND “Bong” AND Go) OR (Senator AND Imee AND Marcos) OR (Justice AND Secretary AND Menardo AND Guevarra OR Justice AND Secretary AND Menardo AND I. AND Guevarra) OR (Epimaco AND Densing) OR (Fredenil AND Fred AND H. AND Castro) OR (Koko AND Pimentel OR Senator AND Aquilino AND Pimentel AND III OR Sen. AND Aquilino AND Pimentel AND III OR Senator AND Aquilino AND Pimentel (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Martín AND Andanar (De AND Lima OR Leila AND De AND Lima)) OR (Senator AND Ronald AND Bato AND dela AND Rosa) OR (Christopher AND Lawrence AND Bong AND Tesoro AND Go) OR (Senator AND Christopher AND Lawrence AND Bong AND Tesoro AND Go) OR (Senator AND Panfilo AND Lacson) OR (Senator AND Manny AND Pacquiao) OR (Salvador AND Panelo) OR (Martín AND Andanar) OR (Pantaleon AND Alvarez)"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "_source": [
      "location_id",
      "display",
      "parent_path",
      "parent_location_id",
      "country",
      "country_code",
      "east",
      "west",
      "north",
      "south",
      "category"
    ]
  }
```

**See examples**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-query-ex-request

Comment: hello and thank you so much for your answer sir @Always Sunny, I'm quite in the intermediate level with ES querying so I got the point of your suggested answer. However, I think this error comes within Lucene - Elasticsearch relationship, that's because I've already encountered many queries, but this one is the longest, besides your suggested answer's query got quite a wrong idea because I'm looking for articles that these **keywords** have appeared, not from locations

Comment: You can use any index name as you wish I just shared my index name with location. The main idea you'll get from my given link. Hope that's help